# Youtube IFrame Player API - Disable Youtube auto resume video where I left off

Tags: javascript, video, iframe, youtube

I'm using the Youtube IFrame Player API to play a video from Youtube.
I want the video to be played from the beginning but Youtube automatically resume the video from where I last left off.

Here is my code:

```
new YT.Player('yt-player', {
        height: '439',
        width: '100%',
        videoId: 'my-video-id',
        startSeconds: 0,
        playerVars: {
                controls: 0,
                color: 'white',
                disablekb: 1,
                enablejsapi: 0,
                modestbranding: 1,
                rel: 0,
                showinfo: 1,
                iv_load_policy: 3,
                start: 0
        },
        events: {
                onReady: function() {
                         this.playVideo();
                }
        }
})
```

I tried using `startSeconds` and `start` parameters but it does not work.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Try to change the `start:0` to `start:1`.

This should reset the video but I don't know the reason.

I tested with direct url with parameters.

1. Example with start=0 [example0](https://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?%20version=3&autoplay=1&start=0)
2. Example with start=1 [example1](https://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?%20version=3&autoplay=1&start=1)

You will see that start=1 will works correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your response.


`start:1` means that the video starts playing from the first second, not from the beginning

Comment: Not sure if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2bk4fdmq/2/) help you. In the fiddle, I use  `player.seekTo(0);` after the player state change to playing.